# python numpy: indexing broadcast

Tags: python, numpy

suppose I have a 3-by-5 array:

```
  a=[[ 1.342,  2.244, -0.412, -1.456, -0.426],
     [ 1.884, -0.811,  0.193,  1.322,  0.76 ],
     [-0.654, -0.788,  1.264,  1.034,  0.356]]
```

and I want to select the 0th element from the first row, 2nd from the second row and 4th from the third row, I would use

```
a[range(3), [0, 2, 4]]
```

the result should be:

```
[1.342, 0.193, 0.356]
```

How to broadcast to more dimensions? suppose now I have a 2-by-3-by-5 tensor:

```
[[[-1.054,  0.068, -0.572,  1.535,  1.746],
  [-0.115,  0.356,  0.222, -0.391,  0.367],
  [-0.53 , -0.856,  0.58 ,  1.099,  0.605]],

 [[ 0.31 ,  0.037, -0.85 , -0.054, -0.75 ],
  [-0.097, -1.707, -0.702,  0.658,  0.548],
  [ 1.727, -0.326, -1.525, -0.656,  0.349]]]
```

For the first dimension `a[0]`, I'd like to select `[0,2,4]`th element, and for `a[1]` I'd like to select `[1,3,2]`th element. Is there a way to do it? If I do it separately for each `a[0]` and `a[1]`, the result should be:

```
print( a[0, range(3), [0,2,4]] )
print( a[1, range(3), [1,3,2]] )

>>>[-1.054  0.222  0.605]
   [ 0.037  0.658 -1.525]
```

Comment: The indexing arrays `broadcast` against in each other in much same as in addition (except without the actual sum).  In the first case you have two (3,) arrays.  In the second you want a set that broadcasts to (2,3), e.g. (2,1),(3,),(3,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do similar [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) by providing an index for the 1st dimension  (make sure it has the correct shape so it can broadcast  correctly):

```
idx = np.array([[0,2,4], [1,3,2]])

a[np.arange(2)[:,None], np.arange(3), idx]    
array([[-1.054,  0.222,  0.605],
       [ 0.037,  0.658, -1.525]])
```

Comment: Thanks @Psidom that works! actually I read the same link you provided before asking this question, but I stuck at the first index: np.arange(2)[:,None]. Could you please explain a bit on why this works?? I've tried using `...`,  `[0, 1]`, `:` but they don't work

Comment: `np.arange(2)[:,None]` creates an array of shape `(2, 1)` instead of `(2,)`. We reshape it so it can broadcast with `idx` array which has shape `(2, 3)`. You can read more about [numpy broadcasting rule here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules).

Answer (score 2):

You could apply [`take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) on the last dimension (`axis=2`). Using the following array of indices:

```
>>> indices = np.array([[0, 2, 4],
                        [1, 3, 2]])
```

However, you first need need to unsqueeeze an additional dimension on `indices` to match the number of dimensions of the indexed array `a`:

```
>>> indices = np.expand_dims(indices, -1)
```

The following `np.take_along_axis` call will gather `a[i][j][indices[i][j]]`:

```
>>> res = np.take_along_axis(a, indices, 2)
array([[[-1.054],
        [ 0.222],
        [ 0.605]],

       [[ 0.037],
        [ 0.658],
        [-1.525]]], dtype=float32)
```

You then have to unsqueeze the last dimension:

```
>>> np.squeeze(res, -1)
array([[-1.054,  0.222,  0.605],
       [ 0.037,  0.658, -1.525]])
```

---

As a one-liner this would look like:

```
>>> np.take_along_axis(a, indices[..., None], -1)[..., 0]
array([[-1.054,  0.222,  0.605],
       [ 0.037,  0.658, -1.525]])
```